# Discord.js: How to send contents of a .txt file in a message?

Tags: discord.js

So i have a **.txt file** with some information, and i would like to somehow send the contents of it in a message. How can this be achieved?

I've tried to think of possible solutions, but I do not believe they will work so, I am asking for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to define `fs`:

```js
const fs = require('fs'); //this is a package that reads files
```

then, you define where the text file is and the encoding:

```js
var textFile = fs.readFileSync('./textFile.txt', {"encoding": "utf-8"})
```

The contents of the text file will be read, and the textFile var will contain them

> send the contents of it in a message

```js
message.channel.send(textFile)
```

Comment: Ohh, it was that simple to do. Thank you for your help sir!

Comment: No problem at all